# Replace some characters in a certain part of a filename

Tags: files, solaris, rename, mv

On Solaris, I've got a script that succesfully do that:

```
USER,REPORT_NAME,DD:MM:HH24.pdf -> USER,REPORT_NAME,DD_MM_HH24.pdf
```

The one-liner is this:

```
for f in *:*; do mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | tr ':' '_'); done
```

But now, I have to undone it, and also, filter by creation date (reports generated the last 15 days, for example). So, for the reports generated the last 15 days, I have to do this rename:

```
USER,REPORT_NAME,DD_MM_HH24.pdf -> USER,REPORT_NAME,DD:MM:HH24.pdf
```

How can I replace only the characters (`_`) in the `DD_MM_HH24` part, and don't touch the `REPORT_NAME` part in the filename? And filter by modification date the reports?

**Posible Solution:**
I've come up with a non very elegant solution.. Is executing 2 times the command, to replace the last occurrence of "_" each time:

```
$ echo "ADMIN,IN_CO_GE,17-09-2015,11_17_06.pdf" |  sed 's/\(.*\)_/\1:/'
ADMIN,IN_CO_GE,17-09-2015,11_17:06.pdf
$ echo "ADMIN,IN_CO_GE,17-09-2015,11_17:06.pdf" |  sed 's/\(.*\)_/\1:/'
ADMIN,IN_CO_GE,17-09-2015,11:17:06.pdf
```

**Final solution**
Thanks to chaos, this is the final solution to my problem:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | nawk -F, '{OFS=",";gsub(/_/, ":", $NF)}1'); done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for that:

```
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | awk -F, '{OFS=",";gsub(/_/, ":", $NF)}1')
done
```

This will replace the `_` with `:`, but only in the last field delimited by `,`:

- `-F,` sets `awk`s delimiter to `,`
- `OFS=",";` sets the ouput field separator to `,`
- `gsub(...)` replace all `_` with `:` in the last field `$NF`
- The `1` at the end is a true condition, that `awk` prints the whole line.

**Edit**: On Solaris, you have to use `nawk` (which is the only `awk` on Solaris system that has the `gsub()` function) instead of the old `awk`:

```
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | nawk -F, '{OFS=",";gsub(/_/, ":", $NF)}1')
done
```

**Edit 2**: For files whose mtime is newer than 30 days:

```
for f in *; do
  [ $(stat -c %Y "") -gt $(expr $(date +%s) - 30 \* 86400) ] && \
    mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | nawk -F, '{OFS=",";gsub(/_/, ":", $NF)}1')
done
```

Comment: Thanks, chaos.. I've got a problem executing this stament: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
mv: Insufficient arguments (1)
Usage: mv [-f] [-i] f1 f2
       mv [-f] [-i] f1 ... fn d1
       mv [-f] [-i] d1 d2
My system is a SunOS 5.10 Generic_147148-26 i86pc i386 i86pc

Comment: @Aitor can you try again? I changed the `gsub()` part

Comment: No, but something change, now the error repeats itself for every file:  for f in *; do
>   mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | awk -F, '{OFS=",";gsub(/_/, ":", $NF)}1')
> done
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
mv: Insufficient arguments (1)
Usage: mv [-f] [-i] f1 f2
       mv [-f] [-i] f1 ... fn d1
       mv [-f] [-i] d1 d2
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
mv: Insufficient arguments (1)
.....

Comment: @Aitor I found the problem. The olf awk in solaris has no `gsub()` function. Please use `nawk` instead.

Comment: one last question.. how can I get in the "loop for" only the files changed in the last 30 days?

Comment: @Aitor see my edit

Comment: wow.. thank you very much, just perfect.. If i could upvote you 10 times I 'd do it! ;)